# Freezing uncooked ‘chicken of the woods’

Tags: freezing, mushrooms

We found and foraged chicken of the woods. We cooked some and also froze some. We did not cook these mushrooms before freezing. Are they still edible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/60145/storing-chicken-of-the-woods-mushrooms

Comment: @zetaprime Not exactly a dupe as that question asks about cooked mushrooms.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Paulette! Your mushrooms should be fine for using in cooked dishes. I would avoid using them uncooked as thawed mushrooms can be soggy/mushy.

We don't have access to any areas to forage fresh mushrooms, but I have bought both fresh (and frozen them) and prepackaged frozen mushrooms. When used in cooked dishes you couldn't tell that they weren't fresh to begin with. Much, much better than anything from a jar or can!